# what's the meaning of "hang on like a loose garment" in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> For the socialists, no less than for the bourgeoisie, everything involves the question of taste, of a viewpoint and of moods. In socialism, as in bourgeois society, things are confined to the surface without ever making contact with the centre of life. In fact, it is much more so in socialism where human life is framed in purpose and anchored to a centre. And yet, the masses are unable to see that this has nothing to do with them, for purpose and centre merely **hang on them like a loose garment.**

--from "aesthetic culture" written by Georg Lukacs

Comment: Please take the time to quote your source correctly and provide the link. Also, share your research.

Comment: i have qoute it from the book i don't know online source

Comment: @MohammadFirouzi: How come you breezed straight past preceding "making contact with the centre of life"? I don't have any problem with the actual metaphoric usage you're querying here, but I've no idea what Lukacs thinks "the centre of life" means.

Answer (score 2):

Loose clothing is a poor fit. And it is easily taken off and replaced with some other clothing. It also shows that the wearer has taken little care in selecting the clothing.

The author is saying that "the masses" take comparatively little care in thinking about "purpose and centre." That is, the masses don't think carefully about purpose, and can easily drop one purpose and take up another with very little thought or care.

It is, thus, a very dismissive statement. It is saying that the masses don't care enough to become informed on the true purpose and centre of life.